# Get AbsoluteExpiration of HttpContext.Current.Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

In my asp.net application I am setting cache like this;

```
 const string key = "MyTestKey";
 object value = true;
 DateTime absoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
 TimeSpan slidingExpiration = Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
 const CacheItemPriority priority = CacheItemPriority.Default;
 CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback = null;
 HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, value, null, absoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration, priority, onRemoveCallback);
```

How can I retrieve back absoluteExpiration of a HttpContext.Current.Cache object on next request? Or can I get TimeSpan of how long remain for cache I set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the expiration or other CacheItem information for the item once it has been added to the System.Web.Caching.Cache, except when the item is being removed (either explicitly by calling Remove, or by cache expiration) or updated. The only methods that exist retrieve the object return the object only.

If you want more advanced Cache functionality, you'll need to look into using something like MemoryCache instead.

Comment: Your reputation and being self confident tells me I should accept your post as an answer :) I will check MemoryCache thanks.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi - you could also add your own class that contains the expiration and your data item.. so you could you have MyCacheItem which you add to the cache, this item has an expiration and Item property.  However, you have to make sure if you update the item that you update the expiration inside as well otherwise it will get out of sync.